# Passing data though a mysql callback function to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback, asynccallback

I'm new to nodejs and still getting the hang of it. I would like the following code to pass back an user into a variable from a database. The connection and the query works as I am getting some data back, but I just can't seem to store it in a global variable.

In this example the variable 'test_user' works (as its in the function itself), but the variable 'test' won't work.

I assume I need to put async and await somewhere but I don't know where.

```
let test;

app.get('/testing', (req, res) => {
    res.send("testing area");
    test = getUserByEmail("w@w", function(result) {
        let test_user;
        if(result.length > 0)
        {
            test_user = result[0];
            console.log(test_user); //logs the result ok
        } else {
            test_user = null;
        }
        return test_user;
    });

    console.log(test); //doesn't log the result

    
});


function getUserByEmail(email, callback) {

    const SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='"+ email +"'";

    connection.query(SELECT_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            return callback(results);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `const`, which means you cannot change the value of that variable using `=`. You have to use `let` instead.

Comment: Oh, right, because you are trying to console.log the value without awaiting the finish of the callback function. If you move the console.log to the end of the callback, you should see the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Use async/await in the get route:

```
app.get('/testing', async (req, res) => {

test = await getUserByEmail("w@w", function(result) {
```

Comment: now, its bringing up an error on the '=', saying Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: sorry about that, should be test = await getUserByEmail("w@w", function(result) {

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still getting my global variable as undefined before the function has run

Comment: You are not assigning any value to the variable test in the beginning. It will be undefined until the database query finishes executing. Are you getting it right inside the router?
If you need it globally, its a good idea to make separate async function for getting user from database.

Comment: I ideally I don't want it in the route function, I'm using password-local to log in. I have got it working by using an object of users perfectly. Now I am trying to connect a mysql database up to it. I have got the register sorted out. However picking up the user from the database to pass through passport is where I am. I am going along the right lines on this?

Comment: Well, if i got it right. You have some function to pass through passport. Make this function async and await for fetching user inside.

Comment: sorry, as I said in the opening paragraph I am a complete beginner. This is what I was trying to aim towards but thought I would test it out before touching the passport code. From the way passport work (the way I see it) you still need a user to be passed to a variable and also for password deserializeUser you need to get the ID of the user.